# Recursive function JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a few functions and need to execute them one after another endlessly.

```
var bGposition = $("ul.sigProClassic li.sigProThumb a.sigProLink img.sigProImg");
function posDown() {
    bGposition.css({
        backgroundPosition: "0% 0%",
    }).animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '100%',
        backgroundPositionY: '100%',
    }, 3000)
 }

function posUp() {
    bGposition.css({
    backgroundPosition: "100% 100%",
    }).animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '0%',
        backgroundPositionY: '0%',
    }, 3000)
}
posUp();
posDown();
posUp();
posDown();
```

I've already found a way to make it work, but I need to call a function every time manually.

The problem is, when using a `callback` I'm getting a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error, after that it's starting to work.

`setTimeout` is not working in this case.

How can i fix it? Please help!

P.S. Sorry for my English!

Comment: You want to use `setInterval` not `setTimeout` for something to repeat after x amount of time, `setTimeout` is just setting a delay not repetition

Answer (score 1):

Add the `posUp` and `posDown` as a callback function to your `jQuery.animate`.

```
var bGposition = $("ul.sigProClassic li.sigProThumb a.sigProLink img.sigProImg");
function posDown() {
    bGposition.css({
        backgroundPosition: "0% 0%",
    }).animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '100%',
        backgroundPositionY: '100%',
    }, 3000, posUp)
 }

function posUp() {
    bGposition.css({
    backgroundPosition: "100% 100%",
    }).animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '0%',
        backgroundPositionY: '0%',
    }, 3000, posDown)
}
posUp()
```

Comment: Thanks!But it not works with backgroundPosition, if we remove them , everything else will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

I've "solved" this problem by adding a callback and removing background-position.Thanks a lot!

```
var bGposition = $("ul.sigProClassic li.sigProThumb a.sigProLink img.sigProImg");
function posDown() {
    bGposition.animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '100%',
        backgroundPositionY: '100%',
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
        queue: true,
        complete: function() {
            bGposition.animate({
                backgroundPositionX: '0%',
                backgroundPositionY: '0%',
            }, {
                duration: 3000,
                queue: true,
                complete: posDown()
            })
        }
    })
}
posDown();
```